# How to fix 'not found ' error in numpy, loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load a file located in my desktop into numpy, python.
However, the code causes an error.

The file consists only of numbers and ',' characters

Also, what is the meaning of `dtype=np.int64`?
What is the difference between `int64`, `int32`, `float`... in `dtype=np...`?

The name of the file that I want to load is `weather` text file
I want to load this file as a `csv` file.

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.loadtxt("weather.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=np.int64)
```

There is `OSError : weather.csv not found`.

Why is there a error message like this?
The file is on my desktop.

Comment: Is your script also in your desktop?

Comment: See [here](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) for your data type doubts

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your file is called `weather.txt`, but your code shows `.loadtxt("weather.csv",`.

Have you tried changing the filename extension in your code from `.csv` to `.txt`?

```
x = np.loadtxt("weather.txt", delimiter=",", dtype=np.int64)
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my edit. OP didn't state the name ended in txt, He said only it was a text file and I might have done a wrong assumption in my edit.

Comment: @progmatico I see. The original text said ".. want to load is 'weather' txt file ...", so I would make the same asumption as you did. We will wait to wait and see if the Asker gives any clarifications.

Comment: I cannot load file as 'weather.csv', so I've already tried 'np.loadtxt("weather.txt", ~) too, but nothing is changed.

Comment: @Ellen are both the python script and the text file in the same folder? How exactly is the text file called in that folder? You have to use the exact filename in your script for it to work.